# What's the correct way to import animations with node bones

Tags: animation, armature, bones, import

I am coding a [Blender Ogre importer for Ogre 1.10](https://github.com/lamogui/ogre_blender_importer). I want to import the animations from the .skeleton but ogre and Blender bones are different:

Ogre:

- A bone is a Node
- Have an offset from parent (translation)
- Have a rotation (quaternion)
- Have a scale

Blender:

- Bones are a pair of 3D points: head and tail
- Can be connected/disconnected from the parent tail
- The offset is relative to parent tail.
- The head-tail length can't be 0

Blender bones cause 2 issues:

- I can't create bones if ogre bone is just a rotation relative to it's parent (because blender will delete the bone automatically)
- I can't just create only "disconnected" bones because the offset is relative to the tail and the head tail length can't be 0...

My question is: How blender import node-based bones usually (in other formats) ?